# Registering CMD Prompt Context Menu

Tags: c#, console, contextmenu

I'm registering a context menu command to produce a hash value of a file. The problem I'm having is the registered command does not keep the command prompt window results in view. When I right click and call "Create Hash", the results flash briefly before closing. Even adding the `pause` below does not leave the results in view. Is there anything I need to add to the registry key to prevent the window from closing?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string menuCommand = "CertUtil -hashfile \"%1\" pause";
    Register("*", "HashFile", "Create Hash", menuCommand);
}
public static void Register(
    string fileType, string shellKeyName,
    string menuText, string menuCommand)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileType) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(shellKeyName) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuText) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuCommand))
        return;

    string regPath = string.Format(@"{0}\shell\{1}", fileType, shellKeyName);

    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(regPath))
    {
        key.SetValue(null, menuText);
    }

    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(
        string.Format(@"{0}\command", regPath)))
    {
        key.SetValue(null, menuCommand);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick and easy solution is to wrap `CertUtil` via your own Console application and add that to the registry *instead* of running `CertUtil` directly.

Let's say the code below is for `CertUtilWrapper`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var proc = new Process 
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo 
        {
            FileName = "CertUtil.exe",
            Arguments = string.Join(" ", args)
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    }.Start();
    Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
    proc.WaitForExit();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
};
```

Then change your code to

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string menuCommand = "CertUtilWrapper -hashfile \"%1\"";
    Register("*", "HashFile", "Create Hash", menuCommand);
}
```

Obviously this requires `CertUtilWrapper` to be in the system `PATH` somewhere, the same as `CertUtil` itself.

There are other alternatives.  You could instead call `cmd`, batch file, or PowerShell script for instance.

Below is how to do it using `cmd`.  This is simple.  Do note the `/k` switch is required to keep the window open.

Note this has the side effect of keeping the `cmd` window open along with a prompt (which can confuse end users depending on your audience).  I'm not fond of this drawback personally.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string menuCommand = "cmd /k CertUtil -hashfile \"%1\"";
    Register("*", "HashFile", "Create Hash", menuCommand);
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear enough. The problem is with the command being run from the registry, not with my application.

Comment: @windowskm So basically you want `CertUtil` to remain open when run from a context menu?

Comment: Yes that's it exactly, it always seems to close instantly.

Comment: I think I prefer the `cmd` method as otherwise my users will have to install or manually copy in the wrapper to the System32 folder, correct?

Comment: @windowskm Correct.  They would have to either place it somewhere in the system `PATH` or edit `%PATH%` to add the location of the wrapper.  That's the drawback of the wrapper approach.

Comment: In the end this was more complicated than I had anticipated. I actually had to register a DLL that ran the command as I needed submenus in my context menu. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!